# Is possible to use a 'variables ' from received value in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a select input and a following function:

```
$(document).on('change','select#country',function(){
var Netherlands = "Code: NL. A currency in Netherlands is Euro (EUR)";
var Poland = "Code: PL. A currency in Poland is Polish Zloty (PLN)";
var xd = $(this).find('option:selected').text()
alert(xd) //use a var from received text (which equal to var)
})
```

And I would like to alert the informations which are under the variables.

So, instead the alert the text of label (Which is e.g. Poland) I would like to use the veriable under this name (which return me info about a certain country).

Is it possible to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can ! I recommend to do with object type . So try like below

```
$(document).on('change','select#country',function(){
var CodeList = {
  Netherlands : "Code: NL. A currency in Netherlands is Euro (EUR)",
  Poland      : "Code: PL. A currency in Poland is Polish Zloty (PLN)"
}
var xd = $(this).find('option:selected').text()
alert(CodeList[xd]) //use a var from received text (which equal to var)
})
```